# Where is my settings.gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm exporting my android project from eclipse to android studio and want to import the facebook SDK to my project.
I'm following the guide the can be found on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/ but when I get to the part where I'm suppose to "update the Gradle files and configure our build-time dependencies" it says that I should open my settings.gradle file, but there is none there! Why is it not there?

Comment: What does your project directory look like? If your project is named XXXX all the java files are inside XXXXProject/XXXX/src, right? Are you looking in XXXX/ or XXXXProject/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The settings.gradle file isn't needed unless you want to add another project to your build. Just create it and you will be fine.

Here are some useful build related questions:

- [How to build an android library with Android Studio and gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)
- [Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)
- [Gradle and Multi-Project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536652/gradle-and-multi-project-structure)

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions are that you didn't migrate your project from eclipse correctly.

Migrating from Eclipse

If you've previously developed for Android using Eclipse and would like to migrate to Android Studio, you should export your projects from Eclipse in order to generate Gradle build files. You can then import your project into Android Studio.

Export from Eclipse

Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).
In Eclipse, select File > Export.
In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.
Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

Your selected project remains in the same location but now contains a build.gradle file and is ready for Android Studio.

Import into Android Studio

In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
Click Import Project.
Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)

Note: It's possible to import an existing Android project to Android Studio even if you don't generate a Gradle build file from Eclipse—Android Studio will successfully build and run projects using an existing Ant build file. However, in order to take advantage of build variants and other advanced features in the future, we strongly suggest that you generate a Gradle build file using the ADT plugin or write your own Gradle build file for use with Android Studio.

[source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#Export)