# How to make gradle modules to be in the same directory?

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm using maven and i'd like to move to gradle.
The problem is that i have module "lib" and module "app", app uses lib. I have to create `settings.gradle` file in 'app' folder with `include :lib` content to make 'app' use 'lib'. I want them to be in the same folder 'project' like this:

```
project
|-lib
|-app
```

instead of:

```
project
|-app
  |-lib
```

I've tried using `include ./lib` but no luck.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

project/settings.gradle:

```
include "app", "lib"
```

project/app/build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile project(":lib")
}
```

For further details, see the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: i've just found similar question for more complex case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536652/gradle-and-multi-project-structure